# IntelliJ IDEA does not read user environment variables

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Spring Boot `2.x` application that I run within IDEA using the usual `Run/Debug Configuration` for Spring Boot. This works fine, but now I have to use some environment variables, and I'm placing them in the `Environment variables` field (from the `Configuration` tab)...but so far it is not picking up those values:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Environment Variables]

```sh
04-15-2021 11:08:13,233 |-  WARN in n.g.e.SimpleDataFetcherExceptionHandler:25 [http-nio-9580-exec-1] - Exception while fetching data (/endpoint) : Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, override_value_here
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, override_value_here
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:309)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
```

It's basically using the default (useless in purpose) values I have in `application.yml`:

```yaml
spring:
  ...
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    password: ${DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:override_value_here}
    url: ${DATASOURCE_URL:override_value_here}
    username: ${DATASOURCE_USERNAME:override_value_here}
```

What am I missing in the IDE configuration to make this work? I'm using `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)` with `Runtime version: 11.0.10+8-b1145.96 amd64` under `Windows 10 10.0`.

> By the way, this is currently working if I run the application via Gradle because it's integrated with a `.env` file that holds the values. If there is a way to make IntelliJ IDEA read that file I would really like to know!

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the sample project to reproduce.